# How to invoke clang++ or g++ to exactly replicate the requirements in two different standard versions

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-warnings, language-lawyer, value-initialization

I'm trying to nail down the differences between N3337 §8.5p7 (C++11) and N3797 §8.5p8 (post C++11) that deal with value-initialization.

**N3337 §8.5p7**:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T
>     is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible
>     default constructor);
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if
>     T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that
>     constructor is called.
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> An object that is value-initialized is deemed to be constructed and thus subject to
>   provisions of this International Standard applying to “constructed”
>   objects, objects “for which the constructor has completed,” etc., even
>   if no constructor is invoked for the object’s initialization.

**N3797 §8.5p8:**

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is
>     user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized
>     and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked,
>     and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is
>     default-initialized;
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> An object that is value-initialized is deemed to be constructed and
>   thus subject to provisions of this International Standard applying to
>   “constructed” objects, objects “for which the constructor has
>   completed,” etc., even if no constructor is invoked for the object’s
>   initialization.

Given these two rules the snippet below should give different results:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Base {
    int i;

    Base(int i):i(i) {}
    Base():i(10) {}
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    int j;

    Derived(int j):Base(j), j(j) {}
    Derived()=default;
};

int main() {
    Derived d{};
    std::cout << "d.i = " << d.i << "  " << "d.j = " << d.j << '\n';
}
```

as follows:

1. According to N3337, the default constructor for `Derived` is called, as `Derived` has a user-provided constructor. The default constructor for `Derived` calls `Base` default constructor, which initializes `Derived::i = 10`, leaving `Derived::j` unitialized.
2. From N3797, as `Derived` has no user-provided default constructor, nor a deleted default constructor, the second bullet point applies. That is, `Derived` is zero-initialized, i.e., both `Derived::i` and `Derived::j` are initialized with 0 and the object `d` is default-initialized, which leaves `Derived::i = 10`.

Although my knowledge of Unixes is minimum, I've been trying to replicate these two cases, using different flags for the compilers clang++ and g++, by trial and error, in Coliru, to no avail. The results so far, all printed `d.i = 10  d.j = 0` **without warnings**.

Comment: I have a very hard time reading a question that begins "Need someone to tell me" and not thinking "Read the damned manual on your own."  Perhaps I'm jumping the gun, but I stopped reading there.  Sometimes *how* you ask a question is more important than what question you're asking.

Comment: I have to agree with @JohnDibling that how you ask can make a difference, it might also help if you could document the different flags combination you attempted to use.

Comment: Are you sure that the compilers you tried already implement the changes?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I've tried with g++ -std=c++11 and std=c++0x with different versions -4.8, -4.7, -4.6.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The results I've obtained so far show that both compilers are already updated to N3797, which is post-C++11.

Comment: There's no way for your program to determine if `d.j` is being initialized to 0 or if it's uninitialized and simply happens to be 0. You could tell if you create a `Derived` in memory that's already initialized, say with placement `new`: `Derived d{42}; ::new (&d) Derived{};`

Comment: The question essentially is, what does `-std=c++11` mean for clang++ and g++, and is there a way to force a mode that uses the origninal "bugged" Standard. I agree it's confusing, as different versions seem to implement a different (monotonically increasing) number of defect reports for their `-std=c++11` mode.

Comment: @Casey As I said I have almost no familiarity with Unixes, but I would expect a warning for a member being used (`cout << ...`), but yet unitialized.

Comment: [The version of Visual C++ used at rextester.com follows the C++11 rule.](http://rextester.com/IMELZ32973 "Code sample at rextester.com") I believe `_MSC_VER = 1800` corresponds to MSVC2013.

Comment: @Dyp Exactly. That's why I tried with -std=c++11 and -std=c++0x. I would expect this last one to emit a warning.

Comment: Hmm the [current gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) say this about `-std=c++11` **and** `-std=c++0x`: *The 2011 ISO C++ standard plus amendments.*

Comment: @Casey That's interesting, but MS compilers still don't compile `= default`and `= delete`. As a matter of fact I'd say that MS compilers don't support the great majority of clauses in N3337.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Ok, if you don't believe me maybe you'll believe [What's New for Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx).

Comment: @Casey As a matter of fact I'd say that MS compilers don't support the great majority of clauses in N3337. I forgot to say that my compiler is VS2010!!. That might explain it.

Comment: @dyp Does that mean the -std=c++11 and -std=c++0x are equivalent?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil It seems so.

Comment: @Casey See my snippet in rextester (http://rextester.com/EGPT1431). It clearly shows that `d.j` is unitialized. It would be nice if I had a MS compiler supporting N3797 to clear up everything. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: This wording change happened in [the resolution of CWG DR 1301](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301) which was accepted at the February 2012 committee meeting. (See also [DR1324](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1324), and [DR1368](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1368).) Changes due to defects (as opposed to new features) are typically incorporated by compilers.

Comment: @Casey Before I read the last things you submitted above, take a look at this (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3019f830132572db). If you change the flags to -4.6 and -std=c++0x you get the unitialized result. So you're right about what you said in an earlier comment. I'll accept that as an answer. A very good answer, indeed. Ths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program in the OP cannot distinguish if `d.j` is being initialized to 0 or if it is uninitialized and coincidentally happens to be 0. This would be clear if the Derived object in question were to be created in memory that is already initialized to a known non-zero value, say with placement new:

```
 Derived d{42};        // d.i and d.j are both 42.
 ::new (&d) Derived{}; // d.i is 0, d.j is 0 per N3797 or 42 per N3337.
```

As [dyp says in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023071/need-someone-to-tell-me-the-compiler-flags-for-clang-or-g-that-would-replica?noredirect=1#comment31605116_21023071), compilers typically track changes due to defects in the standard (as opposed to new features) and include them in their support for a particular standard revision. There is likely no compiler that compiles *exactly* the language as specified in any given standard document given that the standards are constantly in flux. When you tell, e.g., clang 3.4 to compile C++11 the language it actually implements is "the portion of C++11 plus pertinent defect resolutions that we had implemented (IIRC all of it for 3.4) in time for the 3.4 release."

The particular change to the *value-initialization* wording that the OP asks about happened in the resolution of [Core Working Group (CWG) Defect Report (DR) number 1301](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301) which also addressed [DR1324](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1324) and [DR1368](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1368). As a defect resolution, compilers would then have reason to implement the change.

Analysis with various compilers and versions (mostly performed by the OP) demonstrates:

- [VS2013 has not implemented DR1301.](http://rextester.com/IMELZ32973)
- [GCC 4.6.4 also has not.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd896f7a0de6a7d2)
- [GCC 4.7.3 has implemented DR1301.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1595f187ec9d9f2)
- [GCC 4.8.1 implements DR1301 as well.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5c9626788ff0912)

In summary, there's no way to force a compiler to perform *exactly* as specified, but we can usually determine what's going on anyway with some careful analysis.